# Mongodb, выборка из справочника при наличии в другой коллекции

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Есть справочник книг:

**books**

```
{id: 1, name 'book1'},{id: 2, name: 'book2'},{id: 3, name: 'book3'}
```

Также есть коллекция "продление книг"

**book_extension**

```
{id: 1, books: [{id: 2, name: 'book2', id: 3, name: 'book3'}], {id:2}}
```

Вопрос: как из справочника книг **books** вывести только те книги, которые есть в коллекции **book_extension** ?

Comment: Использовать [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: интересно, и как присоединение слева решит эту проблему?

Comment: Прочитайте по ссылке выше со слов "The following operation joins the orders collection with the warehouse collection by the item and whether the quantity in stock is sufficient to cover the ordered quantity"